# grid-template-rows - make two rows flow together as if they are a single div

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a new story template that consists of three divs:

- a photo
- the article
- a set of related links.

On mobile they need to be displayed in that order, while on desktop, I want them in a two column arrangement with the photo and links together and the body text opposite. (I'm struggling to think of a way of doing it with Flexbox ordering whilst still making the two column thing work.)

I've been trying to do this in CSS grid. The problem is an unwanted gap between the photo and related links because the length of the news story (which spans two rows) increases the height of each.

By default the rows on the left have a 50% / 50% split like this:

```
|-------|--------------|
| Photo | News item    |
|       |              |
|       | lorem ipsum  |
|-------| dolor sit    |
| Links | amet,        |
|       | foo, bar baz |
|       | hello world  |
|-------|--------------|
```

I want it:

- to look like this, with the links directly underneath the photo
- to cope regardless of photo height, number of links, article height

```
|-------|--------------|
| Photo | News item    |
|-------|              |
| Links | lorem ipsum  |
|       | dolor sit    |
|       | amet,        |
|       | foo, bar baz |
|       | hello world  |
|-------|--------------|
```

Is this even possible in CSS grid?

`grid-template-rows: minmax()` doesn't seem to help, I can specify, say, (auto,25%), but that'll break as soon as the size of elements changes. The `masonry` option sounds useful, but that's Firefox only.

Comment: Post the code you've tried, so we can try to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just [fit-content()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content_function) or [min-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-content) to achieve your goals. This shrinks the container down to the size of the content. In this case I'm making the top left grid element shrink to the size of the image so the links will always be directly below it.

See annotated example below. Any questions just drop a comment in.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr; /* fit-content(0) also works */
  grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr; /* fit-content(0) also works */
}
.article {
  grid-row: span 2; /* span the article to the two rows */
}

.container > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

img {
  display: block; /* remove descender */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="photo">
   <img src='https://placekitten.com/200/200'>
  </div>
  <div class="article"><h3>News Item</h3>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
  <div class="links">
    <a href='google.com'>Google</a>
    <a href='stackoverflow.com'>Stack Overflow</a>
    <a href='linux.org'>Linux</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: superb, thanks. I'd misunderstood the grid-template-columns|rows syntax…

Comment: You are very welcome William.